# 302 redirect with domain if not authenticated

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

My asp.net application redirect me to the logging page whenever I am not authenticated.

The problem is that the response header location is `://mydomain.com/login` but I want it to be `/login` only.

I'm using a reverse proxy and the domain name is rewritten with the machine name. This result is that when you ask for `://mydomain.com/` the redirection is `://machinename/login`.

I do not want the machine name to be public.

Is there a setting that I can change to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about how to get the real outer host within ASP.NET Core :
Customers only know about `://mydomain.com`. And your reverse proxy forwards requests to `://machinename` (ASP.NET Core Website).

Not sure how your reverse proxy works. But it's much better to configure your proxy to set the host automatically. e.g. configuration for nginx :

```
proxy_redirect           off;
proxy_set_header         Host                    $host;
proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
```

and register a middleware to deal with the `Forwarded` host in your `Startup.cs` .

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost|ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor|ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

By this way, the ASP.NET Core will be able to realize the the real host/port/scheme etc